# Multiplicar strings y operators

Tags: python

Tengo una pregunta, imaginemos que `i` es 1 (Lo demás está abajo) cuando multiplico `i` por v1m me sale 100 unos

Aquí tienen mi código:

```
#variables min
v1m = 100
v2m = 75
v3m = 150
VSM = [v1m, v2m, v3m]
#variables real
v1 = input("¿cuantas v1 tienes? ")
v2 = input("¿cuantas v2 tienes? ")
v3 = input("¿cuantas v3 tienes? ")
VSR = [v1, v2, v3]
i = input("¿cuantas raciones quieres hacer? ")
#codigo
V1 = i*v1m
V2 = i*v2m
V3 = i*v3m
VSMi = [V1, V2, V3]
if "VSMi" > "VSR":
    print("tienes que comprar mas ingredientes")
elif "VSMi" < "VSR":
    print("necesitas", v1m*i, "de V1", v2m*i, " de V2,", v3m*i, "de V3")
```

Gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! No termino de entender cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: me refiero que en V1 = i*v1m me sale un montón de unos en vez de 100.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que no estas multiplicando el entero 1 por 100 sino el string '1' por 100. Cualquier string multiplicada por un escalar n concatena ese string n veces. El resultado de tu operacion `input()` siempre te devuelve un string.

Lo que necesitas hacer es cambiar ese string por un entero (int), y tu codigo deberia funcionar sin problemas:

```
v1m = 100
v2m = 75
v3m = 150
VSM = [v1m, v2m, v3m]
#variables real
v1 = int(input("¿cuantas v1 tienes? ")) # Cambiamos el input a entero
v2 = int(input("¿cuantas v2 tienes? ")) # Cambiamos el input a entero
v3 = int(input("¿cuantas v3 tienes? ") # Cambiamos el input a entero
VSR = [v1, v2, v3]
i = int(input("¿cuantas raciones quieres hacer? ")) # Cambiamos el input a entero
#codigo
V1 = i*v1m
V2 = i*v2m
V3 = i*v3m
VSMi = [V1, V2, V3]
if "VSMi" > "VSR":
    print("tienes que comprar mas ingredientes")
elif "VSMi" < "VSR":
    print("necesitas", v1m*i, "de V1", v2m*i, " de V2,", v3m*i, "de V3")
```

Comment: muchas gracias!